# SOAP web service is configured to run on https, getting error: "Translet class loaded, but unable to create translet instance" while loading wsdl

Tags: java, soap, jboss, wsdl, apache-axis

I have a SOAP web service that is **configured to run only on HTTPS**. HTTP is completely disabled on the server due to security reasons.

I have deployed an **independent war** file on **JBOSS EAP 7.1** for accessing the soap web services.
I am using **axis2** version **1.7.9**.

I want wsdl to return SOAP end location in https instead of http.
For achieving this, I disabled http completely on my server and made following entry in **axis2.xml**:

```
</transportReceiver>
<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
<parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

And made the following changes in **services.xml** corresponding to the web service wsdl:

```
        <parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="modifyUserWSDLPortAddress">true</parameter>
```

and added:

```
    <transports> 
        <transport>https</transport> 
    </transports>
```

I am getting the following stack trace, when I try to hit the services on browser:

```
    Stack Trace:
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Translet class loaded, but unable to create translet instance.
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1753)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1513)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.handleWSDLRequest(ListingAgent.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:277)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Translet class loaded, but unable to create translet instance.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.defineTransletClasses(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.getTransletInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.newTransformer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLPrettyPrinter.prettify(XMLPrettyPrinter.java:157)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1750)
    ... 44 more
```

Please suggest, earlier it was working fine before making the above mentioned changes in services.xml and it is only arising after doing the changes.

Comment: Check this: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1387313

Comment: workaround from https://issues.redhat.com/browse/THORN-1224: The following has to be added to jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

<module name="org.apache.xalan" services="import"/>